# Idea2016 SVN always need press VCS|Refresh File Status before commit

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I work with IntelliJ IDEA 2016 on Win7 and I have an annoying phenomena - Every time I edit a file, the file itself and sometimes other files gets a gray-light-green color[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4oyD.png) and can't be detected changed by IDEA VCS,but the file in system explorer TortoiseSVN is detected changed. To solve this issue I have to press: VCS > Refresh File Status, then it turns gray-blue color[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rxX4.png) and i can commit it.How can it be detected changed automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem just now. And I found it was caused by the Ignored Files setting.
Please check Settings -> Version Control -> Ignored Files to see if that's your case.